# post a form using ajax inside a partial view which loaded on another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, post, partial-views

I'm trying to manage the keywords for each page. i have this class

```
 public class Keyword
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "آدرس")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "کلمات کلیدی")]
    public string KeyWords { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "شرح صفحه")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admins")]
    public ActionResult Create(string Address="")
    {
        Keyword keyword = db.Keywords.Where(k => k.Address == Address).FirstOrDefault();
        if (null == keyword)
        {
            keyword = new Keyword() { Address = Address };
        }
        return PartialView(keyword);
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admins")]
    public ActionResult Create(Keyword keyword)
    {
        keyword.Address = Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery;
        if (db.Keywords.Count(k => k.Address == keyword.Address) > 0)
        {
            var model = db.Keywords.Where(k => k.Address == keyword.Address).FirstOrDefault();
            model.Description = keyword.Description;
            model.KeyWords = keyword.KeyWords;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                //return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
            }
        }
        else if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Keywords.Add(keyword);
            db.SaveChanges();
            //return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
        }

        return PartialView(keyword);
    }
```

and this the partial view

```
@model Stockala.Models.Keyword

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Keyword", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "keywords-div" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <legend>کلمات کلیدی</legend>
            <table class="fields">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KeyWords) :
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.KeyWords, new { style = "width:600px;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KeyWords)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) :
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { style = "width:600px;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <p>
                <input id="keysubmit" type="submit" value="تایید" class="button"/>
            </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    </fieldset>
}
```

and this is how i rendered the partial view inside my _layout.chtml

```
<div id="main">
        @RenderBody()
        @if (User.IsInRole("admins"))
        {
            <div id="keywords-div">
                @Html.Action("Create", "Keyword", new { Address = Request.Url.PathAndQuery })
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

but here is a the problem. when i submit the form, it goes to the Keyword controller and the browser shows only the partial view, but i want to just submit the form and stay in the current page.

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me. Adapted to your situation:

```
@model Stockala.Models.Keyword

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Keyword", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode     = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "keywords-div" }))
{
<div id="keywords-div">
    //Rest of the form body
</div>
}
```

remove the '()' from your "new AjaxOptions ()"

Comment: thanks bro. it didn't work. do you add any references to scripts like jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min or other scripts?

Comment: i used the way described in this page and it worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317141/post-form-data-to-controllers-action-with-ajax

Comment: can you update your questiong with the scripts that get loaded within your page?