# Get value of an input c# mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have input boxes which I need to get the value from so that later they can be redirected to a specific controller, but I don't know how to access the values.  Can someone please give me direction on how to get the values?

```
 <form action="@Url.Action("AddSpecific", "Comment", new { AuthorT ="1", WebSiteT = "1", postIdT = 1, TextT = "1",TitleT = "1" })" method="post">

<h1>
    <label for="Title">Title</label>
    <input name="Title" id="Title" type="text"  required />
</h1>
<h1>
    <label for="Text">Text</label>
    <input name="Text" id="Text" type="text" required />
</h1>
<h1>
    <label for="AuthorSite">AuthorSite</label>
    <input name="AuthorSite" id="AuthorSite" required />
</h1>
<h1>
    <label for="Author">Author</label>
    <input name="Author" id="Author" type="text" required />
</h1>
<h1>a
    <label for="IdOfPost">IdOfPost</label>
    <input name="IdOfPost" id="IdOfPost" type="number" required />
</h1>

<input type="submit" value="Post comment" />
```

Comment: are you trying to get the values in javascript or in c#?

Comment: c# actually although if you can find a solution in java script i would be more than happy

Comment: Grammar and readability.

Comment: You need to so to the MVC site and work through the basic tutorials. In particular, how to use a model, how to render that model in a view using html helpers and how to define you controller methods so that the model is bound when you submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with using a model to pass through and utilize as a parameter for your action.

You need to change your form html so you are not sending default values.  Change:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("AddSpecific", "Comment", new { AuthorT ="1", WebSiteT = "1", postIdT = 1, TextT = "1",TitleT = "1" })" method="post">
```

To:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("AddSpecific", "Comment")" method="post">
```

Your MySpecificObject (the param object for your action).  Note that the property names match the name attribute of your inputs, this is important:

```
public class MySpecificObject
{
   public string AuthorSite {get;set;}
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public string Text {get;set;}
   public string Author {get;set;{
   public string IdOfPost {get;set;}
}
```

The Update Your CommentController:

```
public ActionResult AddSpecific(MySpecificObject mySpecificObject)
{
   //mySpecificObject.IdOfPost
   //do work
}
```

Additionally, if you decide you would like to do this via JavaScript and Ajax, check this StackOverflow post: [Post form data to Controller's action with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317141/post-form-data-to-controllers-action-with-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

When you build your *Form* with the declared attributes, your in essence indicating where it should attempt to *Post*.  Once you've outlined the said attribute the *Submit Button* will execute to that location.  Model View Controller will perform some of your request automatically, so the Controller your pointing to:

```
public ActionResult Submit(int id, string name, string email)
{
     // Utilize parameters.
}
```

So if you outline your form fields with a `name` that matches a parameter in the Controller, MVC will attempt to correlate said field directly to the Controller.  So your current approach may not even need to occur.

Comment: This is my controller                public ActionResult AddSpecific(String AuthorT,String WebSiteT, int postIdT ,String TextT,String TitleT )
        {
         
            Comment C = new Comment { Author = AuthorT, AuthorSite = WebSiteT, IdOfPost = postIdT, Text = TextT ,Title=TitleT,CommentOnPost=null};
            db.Comment.Add(C);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();

        }

Answer (score 0):

Your input elements should have the same name value as the parameter on the controller

For Instance, if your controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult AddSpecific(String AuthorT)
{
    //Do Some Actions
    return View();
}
```

You should have a form that has an element with the name "AuthorT":

```
<form action="@Url.Action("AddSpecific")" method="post">

<h1>
    <label for="Title">Title</label>
</h1>
    <input name="AuthorT" id="AuthorT" type="text"  required />
    <input type="submit" value="Post Comment"/>
</form>
```

See the name value of the input element has the same name as the controller parameter, the controller will pick up this value